# How to turn on laptop's functional keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, laptop, function-keys

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 but key `Fn+F2` `Fn+F3` and etc doesn't work like in Windows 7.

I have laptop ASUS ZenBook UX32VD. How can I enable those keys?

Answer (score 3):

The base install of Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't support, by default, the keyboard functions for your particular machine. You'll need to install drivers for it, basically. [Help.ubuntu.com has an awesome wiki page detailing how you can go about doing that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#Keyboard).

I highly recommend alternative 1 (from the wiki page):

1. [Go here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12054636&postcount=30) and download the attached .deb file
2. Run the following to install it:

   ```
   gzip -d asus-wmi-dkms_999.01_all.deb.gz  
   sudo apt-get install dkms  
   sudo dpkg -i asus-wmi-dkms_999.01_all.deb
   ```

Comment: Though, it may theoretically correct. It is preferable to include the necessary details here and provide the link for reference

Comment: @AnwarShah - While I would normally agree with you, I felt that the wiki page had far more information (caveats, etc) than what could be adequately posted here without copying it verbatim. However, I've updated my answer to include the instructions for alternative 1.