# How do I turn off the FN key?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, function-keys

I got a new keyboard with function keys, but I have to hold the <kbd>FN</kbd> key to use the <kbd>F1</kbd>|<kbd>F12</kbd> keys normally and not to change the volume, brightness, etc.
How do I change this?

Comment: Have you looked at other similar questions? http://askubuntu.com/q/170819/62483 & http://askubuntu.com/q/171166/62483

Comment: Hmmm... in my 3 keyboards the handling of "Fn" is totally hardware, and is invisible on the Linux side (I mean, I have to press Fn+keypad 0 to have "Menu", but `xev` see just the Menu keypress). So this thing should be a setting of the keyboard itself --- maybe a switch or a key combo --- or I fear it is basically impossible. Try with `xev` to see which key events are generated: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys. One of the keyboards has a "Fn lock" option.

Comment: @Lucio; I have, and nothing (including those two) are what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Rmano; This is possible to change on windows, as many laptop keyboards require you to press `FN` in order to use the `F` keys normally.

Comment: If you can change it in Windows it could still be some proprietary magic sequence sent to the keyboard... Try to ask the vendor for Linux support, sometime it works...